# Material UI Table, stop deselecting all rows from allRowsSelected={true} when one row is deselected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this material ui Table element:

```
<Table
  selectable={true}
  allRowsSelected={true}  <----THIS SELECTS ALL ROWS, BUT WHEN ONE ROW IS DESELECTED, IT DESELECTS ALL
  multiSelectable={true}>
    <TableHeader
      displaySelectAll={true}
      enableSelectAll={true}>
      <TableRow>
        <TableHeaderColumn>A</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>B</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn>C</TableHeaderColumn>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>

    <TableBody
      displayRowCheckbox={true}
      deselectOnClickaway={false}>
      {props.columnNames.map( (row, index) => (
        <TableRow key={index} selected={true}>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.A}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.B}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn>{row.C}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

`allRowsSelected={true}` makes all the table rows selected initially. I am passing `columnNames` thru `props` into my component and iterating thru them to display each column. However, when I deselect one row, it deselects all rows.

How can I make it so that when B is deselected, only row B gets unchecked, and A, C remains checked? Like this:

```
X A
  B
X C
```

Do I need to set the state of the selected rows and then do something? If so, how would I implement it? (I've already tried setting state and using `onRowSelection` function but I failed) Or is this a simple Table property option?

Comment: This is a longstanding bug. It's fixed in the `next` branch.